# Select columns based on the difference between two rows

Tags: database, postgresql

I am working on a PostgreSQL database that looks like this:

```
   +--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
   | avg_speed_p0 | avg_speed_p25 | avg_speed_p50 | avg_speed_p75 |
   +--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
1  |     85.15    |     87.23     |     84.16     |     85.44     |
2  |     78.63    |     82.76     |     78.01     |     83.15     |
   +--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Where I have calculated the average speed at day (1) and night (2) from a lot of cars in points with 25 meters in between.

I have made the table by using:

```
create table avg_speeds as
   select * from avg_speed_day
      union
   select * from avg_speed_night
```

I have tried to make a primary key as `day` and `night` by:

```
alter table avg_speed_day add column time varchar
```

and then:

```
insert into avg_speed_day (time) values ('day')
```

but that doesn't work but only gives me:

```
   +--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------+
   | avg_speed_p0 | avg_speed_p25 | avg_speed_p50 | avg_speed_p75 |  time  |
   +--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------+
1  |     85.15    |     87.23     |     84.16     |     85.44     | [null] |
2  |     [null]   |     [null]    |     [null]    |     [null]    |   day  |
   +--------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+--------+
```

I would like to end up with a table where the difference between day (1) and night (2) is calculated, and only the once where the difference is bigger than 5 is shown.

Like this:

```
   +---------------+----------------+
   | diff_speed_p0 | diff_speed_p50 |
   +---------------+----------------+
1  |      6.52     |      6.15      |
   +---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You need a primary key and a way to identify which row is the first and which is the second (matters for the sign of the difference).

Comment: And how do I do that? :)

Comment: You don't need to *do* that, you already need to *have* that, else your question does not make much sense to me...

Comment: I have made the table by using:

   create table avg_speeds as
   select * from avg_speed_day
    union
   select * from avg_speed_night

So I do not yet have any primary key. But is there a way to get it?


I have tried with:

   alter table avg_speed_day add column time varchar

and then:

   insert into avg_speed_day (time) values ('day')

but that dosn't work.

Comment: That only gives med:

avg_speed_p0  I  avg_speed_p25  I  avg_speed_p50  I  avg_speed_p75   I  time
+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+
85.15                I    87.23                 I     84.16                I      85.44               I   [null]
[null]                 I     [null]                 I      [null]                 I       [null]               I     day

Comment: I meant to write me*. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your comments show that you receive these two rows from some other tables or views.

Use these directly like this:

```
WITH day   AS (SELECT avg_speed_p0, avg_speed_p25, avg_speed_p50, avg_speed_p75
               FROM avg_speed_day),
     night AS (SELECT avg_speed_p0, avg_speed_p25, avg_speed_p50, avg_speed_p75
               FROM avg_speed_night)
SELECT CASE WHEN abs(day.avg_speed_p0 - night.avg_speed_p0) > 5
            THEN day.avg_speed_p0 - night.avg_speed_p0
       END AS avg_speed_p0,
       CASE WHEN abs(day.avg_speed_p25 - night.avg_speed_p25) > 5
            THEN day.avg_speed_p25 - night.avg_speed_p25
       END AS avg_speed_p25,
       CASE WHEN abs(day.avg_speed_p50 - night.avg_speed_p50) > 5
            THEN day.avg_speed_p50 - night.avg_speed_p50
       END AS avg_speed_p50,
       CASE WHEN abs(day.avg_speed_p75 - night.avg_speed_p75) > 5
            THEN day.avg_speed_p75 - night.avg_speed_p75
       END AS avg_speed_p75
FROM day CROSS JOIN night;
```

There is no way in SQL to omit a column dynamically.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had made a typo, but now everything works. Thanks.